# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: spring-boot, ldap

I am trying to use ldap authentication.

Here is my code.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {     
        auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=AppUsers")
        .contextSource()
         .url("ldap://xxx.corp.example.com/dc=mycompany,dc=com")
         .and()
        .passwordCompare()
         .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
         .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
        }
}

application.yml

server:
   port : 8080

logging.config: config/logback.xml

spring:
  ldap:
    embedded:
     base-dn: dc=mycompany,dc=com
     credential: 
       username: uid=dsb-admin
       password: abc123
     ldif: schema.ldif
     port: 123
     validation:
       enabled: false

schema.ldif 
dn: cn=dsb-admin,ou=NAppUsers,dc=mycompany,dc=com
objectclass: Services
cn: dsb-admin
ou: NAppUsers
uid: dsb-admin
userPassword: abc123
uniqueMember: uid=dsb-admin,ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com

dn: cn=AccountID,ou=raccounts,ou=NAppUsers,dc=mycompany,dc=com
objectclass: AccountService
cn: AccountID
ou: raccounts
uid: AccountID
userPassword: YYY
uniqueMember: uid=AccountID,ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com
```

Here is the info I was given to use. I am not sure if I am mapping them correct or not.

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -h xxx.corp.example.com-p 123 -D "cn=dsb-admin,ou=NAppUsers,o=Services" -w abc123 -b "ou=raccounts,dc=mycompany,dc=com" "(&(ObjectClass=AccountService)(AccountID=YYY))"
xxx.corp.example.com
```

I am getting error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource@6f3f0fae of type class org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.spectrum.tos.BaseApplication.main(BaseApplication.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource@6f3f0fae of type class org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource@6f3f0fae of type class org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter$CompositeObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.access$300(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer$ContextSourceBuilder.build(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:535)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer$ContextSourceBuilder.access$600(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:432)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.getContextSource(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:599)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.build(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.configure(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:376)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.configure(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:383)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:329)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:272)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/JdkVersionhere is some more error logs.

Comment: I got rid of errors by removing versions in the dependency label.